# Why does root get "Permission denied" when trying to create this folder?

Tags: 14.04, permissions, root

Why does root get "Permission denied" when trying to create this folder?

```
root@donhy:/var/www/clients/client2/web2# mkdir bin
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘bin’: Permission denied
root@donhy:/var/www/clients/client2/web2# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
root@donhy:/var/www/clients/client2/web2# whoami
root
root@donhy:/var/www/clients/client2/web2# getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x    
root@donhy:/var/www/clients/client2/web2# lsattr 
-------------e-- ./web
-------------e-- ./private
-------------e-- ./log
-------------e-- ./ssl
-------------e-- ./tmp
-------------e-- ./cgi-bin
-------------e-- ./webdav
root@donhy:/var/www/clients/client2/web2# lsattr ..
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on ../satmike.com
----i--------e-- ../web1
----i--------e-- ../web6
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on ../fishingrodcaddy.com
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on ../mlconsult.net
----i--------e-- ../web3
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on ../vacujig.com
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on ../lucycakeshop.com
----i--------e-- ../web4
----i--------e-- ../web2
root@donhy:/var/www/clients/client2/web2# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       913G  2.4G  865G   1% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            991M  4.0K  991M   1% /dev
tmpfs           200M  488K  200M   1% /run
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none           1000M   76K 1000M   1% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1       180M   34M  134M  20% /boot
root@donhy:/var/www/clients/client2/web2# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS \n \l
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is right there in the `lsattr` output:

```
# lsattr ..
----i--------e-- ../web2
```

The folder is immutable, even by root.

Comment: How does one deal with that by the way?

Comment: @kos use `chattr` to remove the immutability attribute.

Comment: @kos: You need `chattr -i file`